# Network fluctuation problem

Tags: internet, lan

In my working company we have a 3 Internet providers and interconnected with each other through switches. Every time some PC's suddenly can't browse to the internet but they have connection. I try to ping test the IP of 3 internet providers on each PC's and i get a good result(no request time out). Sometimes all PC's can browse/use the internet and some are not. Also the WIFI sometimes we can connect but sometimes can't. Our main connection is around 4mpbs and the 2 cisco wifi connected there(1st flr and 2nd flr). I don't know what to do. this is my everyday problem.

Comment: I think that in order to help you, we will need more information on your network infrastructure. What is your router model, what is the WAN traffic distribution algorithm (Round Robin/Load Balancing/Etc). Also, you stated that the computers were able to ping the WAN IPs, but can you go beyond your router with the ping (e.g. Google). Also, are the computers connected to a switch, then the router? Finally, you might want to consider investigating DNS resolution problems. Please let me know if you find anything.

Comment: The 4mbps(main internet provider) connected to a CISCO LINKSYS E1200 then connected to a 24 ports switch( 3COM) and to 24 ports switch D-LINK and connected to 8 port swtich D LINK. so that this CISCO LINKSYS connected to a 3 SWITCH. The 2nd internet provider(i don't know how many mbps) connected only into a 24 ports switch( 3COM). And the 3rd Internet provider connected only in a switch into one of the workstation here(I don't know why there's a switch here, maybe because one of the designated LAN port of their workstation malfunctioning that's why they using this switch. TIA

Comment: Can you include a diagram?  Are all the devices in the same VLAN?  Where does the WIFI fit in?  What is the default gateway of the PCs?

Comment: 192.168.1.219
192.168.1.220
192.168.1.221

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Athan, As other guys suggested, you would need to provide more information but you need to bear in mind that pinging and browsing are different.Also we don't know where you are pinging. Browsing first of all requires connectivity to the target node, do you have it? If yes, then drill down on other mechanisms. Does your DNS work? Can you resolve addresses? Did you try doing nslookup? You say some nodes can access while others can't. Is there a difference in their DNS configuration? Have you checked your devices' logs for any event that may give you a clue?

So I ended up asking more questions then you unfortunately.